# Issue getting my objects properties

Tags: javascript, object

Hi guys I have just started learning to code and I have hit a road block in accessing the properties of the object I have created.

Here is my object.

```
var restaurantOrder = {
  "my entree": "cheeseburger",
  "my side": "fries",
  "the drink": "water"
};
```

I would like to get the value of entree however nothing I am trying seems to work  :(

Here is what I have tried.

```
var entreeValue = restaurantOrder.my entree;
var entreeValue = restaurantOrder[my entree];
var entreeValue = restaurantOrder.[my entree];
var entreeValue = restaurantOrder.["my entree"];
```

None of the above lines work :( Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `var entreeValue = restaurantOrder["my entree"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the properties of your **`restaurantOrder`** object have spaces, you will need to use `[]` to access them. You cannot use `.` like you can with a property name that is a single word.

Also, because of the spaces you will need to enclose the property name with quotes, so either:

```
var entreeValue = restaurantOrder["my entree"];
```

or

```
var entreeValue = restaurantOrder['my entree'];
```

will work.